# Placement of 'approximately'

Tags: adverb-placement

Can I use 'approximately' in 'he becomes approximately in his twenties' instead of 'he becomes in approximately his twenties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, "in his twenties" is a ten-year range- that's already approximate, so there is no need to add "approximately". If you specified an exact age, for example 27, you could add "approximately", meaning plus or minus a couple of years.

Second, In some languages, there is no present-tense word for **is**, so people use a word equivalent to **become** instead, for example **baqa** in arabic. In English, you don't use **become** about somebody's current age: in English, you just use **is**. You might, however, use **become** when somebody reaches a specific age:

> He inherited a lot of money when he became 21

Possible corrected versions of your sentence would therefore be:

> He is in his twenties.
> He is approximately 27.